# Python 3 sqlite parameterized SQL-query

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I've been trying to make a parameterized SQL-query with Python 3 and sqlite module and succeeded with just one variable. However when using two variables, I get an `IndexError: tuple index out of range` error. Any suggestions as to what is causing this error?

```py
sql = ("select exists(SELECT * from USERS where PASSWORD = '{0}' AND USERNAME = '{1}')")
args = (var1,var2)
cursor = database_connection.execute((sql).format(args))
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Never** fill in raw entries in your sql command, this is calling for sql injection attacks.

Use the built-in fill-in function.

```
sql = "select exists(SELECT * from USERS where PASSWORD = ? AND USERNAME = ?)"
args = (var1,var2)
cursor = database_connection.execute(sql, args)
```

Comment: Nice. You fixed the error by using `*args` (but forgot to say it...), and insisted in correctly using parameterized queries.

Comment: Your suggestion throws a "TypeError: function takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)" error. Also one of the parenthesis is missing in the first row.

Comment: Sorry, fixed that.