# How to insert tuple element raw data into SQL table?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyodbc

I am trying to insert data into my SQL table via Python.

My code is:

```
sql = "INERT INTO TABLE VALUES" + str(tuple(row))
cursor.execute(sql)
```

The issue I have is that I am getting syntax errors on words such as *table's* due to the apostrophe.

I cannot use:

```
replace('\'','\'\'')
```

on the `str` because that would change the whole SQL insert.

Is it possible to insert the row data of each element inside a tuple to eliminate this issue?

Comment: You can use insert with parameters, as explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45343693/10961342) post, or [here](https://pynative.com/python-sqlite-insert-into-table/). That will escape the special characters for you.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working for some strange reason.

sql = ''' INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES ('?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?')'''
args = tuple(row)
cursor.execute(sql, args)

I keep getting the error: pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('The SQL contains 0 parameter markers, but 11 parameters were supplied', 'HY000')

Comment: Don't believe you enclose question mark markers in their own apostrophes.  You should also provide the list of table columns: INSERT INTO table_name (column_list) VALUES (?, ?, ...)

Comment: that worked, thanks!!